# not being asked to set password for mysql installation

Tags: mysql, installation

I downloaded the mysql installer and installed it as needed. However, i am not getting the option to configure the password. I chose full installation. I have looked up tutorials and all of them have one thing in common. After downloading and installing components, they are shown password configuration screen. While in my case, after installation, it just shows installation completed and launch on closing the setup.

I open the workbench and find no mysql server. I tried creating one but it asks password for username 'root'. So network remains unestablished. Also i tried all sorts of password that i looked up on previous stack overflow answers. Some say, password is by default empty, just 'password' etc. But nothing works. I need help. Thankyou.

Comment: login as `root` leave password empty, so you get to login and then add a password to root

Comment: Is your MySQL installed on your local machine or another machine and you are trying to connect remotely

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for answering, yes MySQL is installed on local machine. Also i tried leaving password empty and tested the connection, but it gives cannot connect to local host.

Comment: And you are sure that the MySQL instance is started

Comment: @RiggsFolly I dont get the meaning of 'MySQL ' instance. Do you mean about the server? In that case no.

Comment: I mean did you start the MySQL deamon/service